# Using Boto3 to upload a file to Amazon WorkDocs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

According to the [Amazon WorkDocs SDK page](https://aws.amazon.com/workdocs/sdk/), you can use Boto3 to migrate your content to Amazon WorkDocs.  I found the entry for the [WorkSpaces Client](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/workdocs.html#client) in the Boto3 documentation, but every call seems to require a "AuthenticationToken" parameter.  The only information I can find on AuthenticationToken is that is it supposed to be a "Amazon WorkDocs authentication token".

Does anyone know what this token is?  How do I get one?  Is there any code examples of using the WorkDocs Client in Boto3?

I am trying to create a simple Python script that will upload a single document into WorkDocs, but there seems to be little to no information on how to do this.  I was easily able to write a script that can upload/download files from S3, but this seems like something else entirely.

Comment: Can you please share your code here,I guess you have missed to provide aws secret key there.

Comment: @AshishBainade - There is no code.  I have no idea what to put in the AuthenticationToken parameter.  In theory, I should be able to do something like:

import boto3
client = boto3.client('workdocs')
response = client.describe_root_folders(
    AuthenticationToken='???',
    Limit=20,
    Marker=''
)

to get a listing of the items in the root folder, but I don't know what to put into the "AuthenticationToken" parameter.

Comment: This means you have not configured aws account. please do pip install awscli & do aws configure as explained at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html .Once this is done your code should work.

Comment: Did you ever work this out? There does not appear to be any useful examples for python workdocs